# Passing relative path file name in csv config element in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I want to pass relative path file name in csv config element in jmeter.i have used ./filename.csv but the jmeter script doesn't work .I have also used ../filename.csv but jmeter script doesn't work.

Need resolution  to pass relative path file name in csv config element in jmeter.i have used ./filename.csv but the jmeter script doesn't work .I have also used ../filename.csv but jmeter script doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Relative to what?

As per [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) documentation:

> Relative file names are resolved with respect to the path of the **active test plan**.
>
> csvdata.txt and ./csvdata.txt - then these are treated as different files

If you have `filename.csv` in the same directory as your .jmx test plan - just use `filename.csv`, the `../filename.csv` construction will look for the `filename.csv` file in the **parent folder** for the active test plan.

If you want to know the full path to the current base directory - look for `FileServer` entry in the [jmeter.log file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging)

```
INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Set new base='/this/would/be/the/base/for/relative/CSV/file/lookup'
```

you will see where JMeter tries to load the CSV file in the same jmeter.log file

Comment: Thanks for the response. The issue was fixed by mentioning relative path as filename.csv and placing the csv file in the same path as that of jmeter script